# Pass the jquery slide up command for some div on url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I'm using jquery slide up/down for some divs on a drupal website.
I would like to know if it is possible to pass the slide up command to a specific div on the url.

Example domain.com/?q=node/13/#div1&slideup

Thanks a lot for any help,
David D.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help.

I've implemented Cecchi suggestion for while, but after some time I start needing some more flexibility (to change the class for other two divs according with the main div), so I made some changes.

I'm using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = window.location.pathname.split('&');
   var id = url[1]
   $("#div" + id).slideDown("slow");
   $("#button_slide" + id).addClass('button_slide_active');
   $("#product_frame" + id).addClass('product_frame_active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `window.location.hash` to get the "div1&slideup" part of your URL.  If you do that inside an onLoad event handler, you can subsequently do whatever you want.

Here's some (un-tested) sample jQuery code to give you an idea (technically it's onReady, not onLoad, but same difference):

```
$(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var divId = hash.split('&')[0];
    $(divId).slideUp();
});
```

Comment: window.location.hash starts with "#". Make sure you exclude the hash.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you'll have to parse the location.hash property and make sure you aren't using the hash for anything else (i.e. actual anchors):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(location.hash.substr(-8) === '&slideup') {
    $(location.hash.substr(0, location.hash.indexOf('&'))).slideUp();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, now as I'm starting to understand this logic, I would like to clean a litle bit my javascript code...

Maybe you can give me some suggestion.

I'm using the following code up to div10, I would like to have this with only one instance of code for all divs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button_slide1,#link_1,#link_1_1,#link_1_2").click(function(){
$("#div2, #div3, #div4, #div5, #div6, #div7, #div8, #div9, #div10").slideUp("slow");
$("#button_slide2, #button_slide3, #button_slide4, #button_slide5, #button_slide6, #button_slide7, #button_slide8, #button_slide9, #button_slide10").removeClass('botao-active');
$("#product_frame2, #product_frame3, #product_frame4, #product_frame5, #product_frame6, #product_frame7, #product_frame8, #product_frame9, #product_frame10").removeClass("product_frameactive");

$("#div1").slideToggle("slow");
$("#button_slide1").toggleClass("botao-active");
$("#product_frame1").toggleClass("product_frameactive"); return false;
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button_slide2,#link_2,#link_2_1").click(function(){
$("#div1, #div3, #div4, #div5, #div6, #div7, #div8, #div9, #div10").slideUp("slow");
$("#button_slide1, #button_slide3, #button_slide4, #button_slide5, #button_slide6, #button_slide7, #button_slide8, #button_slide9, #button_slide10").removeClass('botao-active');
$("#product_frame1, #product_frame3, #product_frame4, #product_frame5, #product_frame6, #product_frame7, #product_frame8, #product_frame9, #product_frame10").removeClass("product_frameactive");

$("#div2").slideToggle("slow");
$("#button_slide2").toggleClass("botao-active");
$("#product_frame2").toggleClass("product_frameactive"); return false;
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button_slide3,#link_3,#link_3_1").click(function(){
$("#div1, #div2, #div4, #div5, #div6, #div7, #div8, #div9, #div10").slideUp("slow");
$("#button_slide1, #button_slide2, #button_slide4, #button_slide5, #button_slide6, #button_slide7,  #button_slide8, #button_slide9, #button_slide10").removeClass('botao-active');
$("#product_frame1, #product_frame2, #product_frame4, #product_frame5, #product_frame6, #product_frame7,  #product_frame8, #product_frame9, #product_frame10").removeClass("product_frameactive");

$("#div3").slideToggle("slow");
$("#button_slide3").toggleClass("botao-active");
$("#product_frame3").toggleClass("product_frameactive"); return false;
});
});
```